# "Element " selector in Primefaces CSS

Tags: css, primefaces

What does "element" selector in Primefaces CSS mean/do? And how to access it, change css rules inside it?.

[please check this image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRUkm.png)

Background: I am trying to change width of PrimeFaces element, selectOneMenu for example, but what seems to be blocking me is style rule inside element{}- min-width in my case. I would like to override it in custom css or with style attribute but don't know how to access it.

I've unsuccessfully tried:

- p:selectOneMenu style="min-width:100px"
- applying styleClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be better to stop that inline style attribute, you could override it with css using the !important:

```
.ui-selectonemenu { min-width: 400px !important; }
```

Comment: @AgnesR great! Mark answer as accepted if you can. Best of luck!